# Can you tell whether a chart is using Helm 2 or 3 from the chart itself?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was wondering if there is anyway to programmatically tell whether a given chart is using Helm 2 or Helm 3?

I know that apiVersion in Chart.yaml has been bumped to v2. But is it definite that apiVersion: V2 correspond to Helm 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to documentation

> The apiVersion field should be v2 for Helm charts that require at least Helm 3. Charts supporting previous Helm versions have an apiVersion set to v1 and are still installable by Helm 3.

To check a chart version from command line, run

```
helm show chart  .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried the `helm show chart .` command, but it seems like it is printing out all of the chart info at once. Is there a way to just get the apiVersion? Other wise I might need to use tools like grep to do it.